# How to edit GNOME Activities so it will only show the currently opened applications?

Tags: gnome, activities-overview

Is this possible to edit the GNOME Activities Overview so it will show the apps only, without the dock in the left and the text-box on top?

To clarify, I am using [apps-menu](https://github.com/gcampax/gnome-shell-extensions) extension that shows all the installed apps in the top bar so there is no need for me to use the Activities to find installed apps anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite certainly, this, in principle, could be implemented by a Gnome Shell extension. However, unless you can develop one for yourself, you have to look among existing extensions on the Gnome Shell Extensions website. The issue is that an extension may not anymore work on your version of Gnome Shell.

At least you will probably find a working extension that removes the Dash ("Dock"). A search for "Hide Dash" reveals several extensions. [No Dash in Overview](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2654/no-dash-in-overview/) and [Hide Dash (new)](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3034/hide-dash-new/) are two options that work on the latest Ubuntu LTS 20.04.

Hiding the Search box may be more difficult. An old extension, [Disable Search](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/203/disable-search/), has not been updated.